# In terms of performance, is it best to create a custom UICollectionViewCell in the storyboard or in a separate xib file?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My main interface contains a **collection view**. I have a **separate xib file for my custom cell**.

I noticed the method `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: for:)` is expensive in terms of CPU (according to Time Profiler tests I made). 
I use to need that custom cell in different collectionviews but not anymore.

So I'm wondering if it would be best to move my custom cell to my storyboard (inside my collection view) and delete that xib file? Any other advice to increase the performance when dequeing custom cells in general in welcome!

Comment: I very much doubt that moving it to the storyboard would help.  How large is your cell? how complex is it? are you creating gestures or other intractable element in the cell?  do you have scrollviews inside the cell? How many cells are being displayed at on time?

Comment: The cell is selectable (tap gesture), there are buttons inside it, no scrollviews, animations can be displayed inside it, some elements are hidden or not depending on the case. There are 2 columns of cells, so about 10 cells always displayed (depending on the screen size).

Comment: Are you sure you are reading Time Profiler correctly?  Even if the cell loading is expensive it should only happen ~10 times.  Are you doing anything in `prepareForReuse`?

Comment: Nothing in `prepareForReuse`. I use a `setCell` method to configure my cell, and `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` for rounding corners. I may not be reading Time Profiler correctly. I see 73ms for `dequeueReusableCell`.

Comment: 73ms does not seem like a lot to me.  You could try using a plain UICollectionViewCell ( ie something like `[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];)` and see how long it take then to give you a baseline.